# How do I preserve function names when bundling and minifying with Webpack and TerserPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, es6-modules, terser

I'm trying to bundle my JS module and I need to preserve the function names as these functions will be referenced in external codebases. Below is my webpack.config.js file and as you can see, I've tried every possible option to preserve the function names but nothing is working. Any ideas?

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    mode: 'production',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              keep_fnames: true,
              keep_classnames: true,
              compress: {
                keep_classnames: true,
                keep_fnames: true
              },
              mangle: false
            },
          }),
        ],
      },
    output :{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like the setup is correct and nothing wrong with it so I guess the issue is related with what you haven't shared here. Could you create a minimal reproducible repo for us then?